# Crossfilter and DC.js: reduce to unique number

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

In the example below, I am trying to sum by unique occurence of `Respond_Id`. eg. in this case, it should be in total `3`, `"Respond_Id"` being `258,261` and `345`.

This is my data:

```
{"Respond_Id":258,"Gender":"Female","Age":"18-21","Answer":424},
{"Respond_Id":258,"Gender":"Female","Age":"18-21","Answer":428},
{"Respond_Id":261,"Gender":"Male","Age":"22-26", "Answer":427},
{"Respond_Id":261,"Gender":"Male","Age":"22-26",  "Answer":432},
{"Respond_Id":345,"Gender":"Female","Age":"27-30","Answer":424},
{"Respond_Id":345,"Gender":"Female","Age":"27-30","Answer":425},
{"Respond_Id":345,"Gender":"Female","Age":"27-30","Answer":433},
```

I know I should use group reduce for this, so I tried (adapted from an example):

```
var ntotal =  answerDim.group().reduce(
                function(p, d) { 
                    if(d.Respond_Id in p.Respond_Ids){
                        p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id]++;
                    }
                    else {
                        p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id] = 1;
                        p.RespondCount++;
                    }
                    return p;
                },
                function (p, d) {
                    p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id]--;
                    if(p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id] === 0){
                        delete p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id];
                        p.RespondCount--;
                    }
                    return p;
                },
                function () {
                    return {
                        RespondCount: 0,
                        Respond_Ids: {}
                    };

                }
            );
```

Then:

```
numberDisplay
         .group(ntotal)
         .valueAccessor(function(d){ return d.value.RespondCount; });

     dc.renderAll();
```

But seems not working. Does someone know how to make it work ? Thank you

Comment: It looks to me like this should basically work. What kind of error are you getting and can you please provide an example with full working code? If you don't want to fiddle with reducers yourself, you may also want to look at Reductio as an option: https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-exception-aggregation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I am getting when logging d in the valueAccessor  is this: {"key":433,"value":{"RespondCount":1,"Respond_Ids":{"345":1}}}

Comment: You need to share a complete example with us. I would guess that your dimension definition and group definition are conflicting, but since you don't share your dimension definition, I can't really tell.

Comment: Also (and sorry for the multiple comments), please share what you would expect/want to see. See here for further tips on examples in questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The result I would like to have is the total number of respondant based on their Respond_id. In the example above it should be 3. Here is a fiddle of my code . https://jsfiddle.net/wa9oxsdg/6/. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your JSFiddle, your setup is like this:

```
var RespondDim       =  ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.Respond_Id;});
var ntotal           =  RespondDim.group().reduce(
                                function(p, d) { 
                                    if(d.Respond_Id in p.Respond_Ids){
                                        p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id]++;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id] = 1;
                                        p.RespondCount++;
                                    }
                                    return p;
                                },
                                function (p, d) {
                                    p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id]--;
                                    if(p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id] === 0){
                                        delete p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id];
                                        p.RespondCount--;
                                    }
                                    return p;
                                },
                                function () {
                                    return {
                                        RespondCount: 0,
                                        Respond_Ids: {}
                                    };
                                 });
```

What is important to note here is that your group keys, by default, are the same as your dimension keys. So you will have one group per respondent ID. This isn't what you want.

You could switch to using `dimension.groupAll`, which is designed for this use case, but unfortunately the `dimension.groupAll.reduce` signature is slightly different. The easiest fix for you is going to be to just define your dimension to have a single value:

```
var RespondDim       =  ndx.dimension(function (d) { return true;});
```

Now you'll see that `ntotal.all()` will look like this:

```
{key: true, value: {RespondCount: 3, Respond_Ids: {258: 2, 261: 2, 345: 3}}}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v0rdoyrt/2/

Comment: Thank you very much. You save my day!

Comment: Another question, how do I access RespondCount, if I want to use it in some calculation outside of dc/crossfilter? I have tried ntotal.all().value.RespondCount but it seems not to work. Thank you

Comment: Do `console.log(ntotal.all())` and you'll see the problem. It returns an array, each element of which has a `.value` with the `RespondCount`. So `ntotal.all()[0].value.RespondCount` should get you something, though perhaps not what you want.

Comment: Hi Ethan, I have a question related to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585979/grouping-in-crossfilter , you might be from good help. Thank you

Comment: Please don't use previous questions to direct people to new and relatively unrelated questions. I'll see them and answer if I'm able to :-)