# Crossfilter dimension of joined table without repeating values

Tags: mysql, dc.js

I will preface this with that I am both relatively unfamiliar with SQL and dc.js. I feel the solution to this is likely pretty simple.

I am currently drawing a group of charts based on a join of two tables that results in a form similar to the following:

```
Subject | Gender | TestName
------- | ------ | --------
1       | M      | Test 1 
2       | M      | Test 1
1       | M      | Test 2
2       | M      | Test 2
```

Essentially, a lot of unique data that is repeated on the join due to TestName changing per subject. The join is on `Subject`.

I have one bar chart for `Gender`, which can be either `M` or `F`. I also have a bar graph of a count of each test (`TestName`) and how many subjects were present in that test. As you can tell from the join, a single subject can and often is a member of more than one test.

My issue is that when I crossfilter this data, the counts for each test is correct (here, it would be 2 each), but my gender information is inflated (4, instead of 2) since it counts what should be each unique subject every time it appears in this joined data set. I want my charts to display `n` Subjects for Gender, but instead it displays `n * 'number of tests'`.

Is there a way to chart the correct count per test case but keep my other charts displaying only a maximum count of unique subjects while keeping my crossfilter working?

Comment: If you want to use a helper library, Reductio has exception aggregation for this: https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#exception-aggregation Otherwise you'll have to write custom reducers. Here is the latest SO question regarding that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415562/crossfilter-and-dc-js-reduce-to-unique-number/45420959#45420959 It's tough to get this right, so if you go the custom reducer route and are having trouble, please feel free to ask about that.

Comment: @EthanJewett Thanks for linking a related question  – it was difficult to search for related issues not knowing exactly how to word my original question. I will give it and Reductio a look.

Comment: No worries. It's not easy to find them and you have to know to look at Crossfilter stuff as well. Maybe we should suggest getting something into the dc FAQ.